# make new line in json file / angular2

Tags: angular

after i get the data for the first row i wanna to have a new row 
 in json file to get the data for second row ...

```
columns: payrollRows,

  generateRows(payrolls){
  var payrollRows = [];
  for(let payroll of payrolls){
    var wageTypeId = { 
        text: `${payroll.wageTypeId}`,
        fontSize: 10,
        width: 50,                                                                      
        alignment: 'left',
        margin:[0,10,0,0]
    }
    var description = { 
        text: `${payroll.wageType.description}`,
        fontSize: 10,
        width: 50,                                                                      
        margin:[0,10,0,0]
    }

        payrollRows.push(wageTypeId);
    payrollRows.push(description);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. If you want a new line in a string, how about `\n`?

Comment: If not, please be a bit more specific what you want to achieve.